# Understanding Java code and make it jQuery. (loginpage)

Tags: java, jquery

I'm trying to understand a login-procedure to a balance-only login page at a bank.
There is already a project that has the procedure in Java, but i'm not too familiar with it so I cant fully understand it.
(https://github.com/liato/android-bankdroid/blob/master/bankdroid-legacy/src/main/java/com/liato/bankdroid/banking/banks/OKQ8.java)

I would like to make it in jQuery.

My attempt is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
var user_id="8312345678";
var password="secret";
var pemUrl="https://nettbank.edb.com/Logon/index.jsp?domain=0066&from_page=http://www.okq8.se&to_page=https://nettbank.edb.com/cardpayment/transigo/logon/done/okq8";
var loginUrl="https://nettbank.edb.com/Logon/logon/step1";
var epochTime=Date.now();
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    type: 'post',
    data: ({
        'p_tranid':epochTime,
        'p_errorScreen':'LOGON_REPOST_ERROR',
        'n_bank':'',
        'empty_pwd':'',
        'username': user_id,
        'password': password
    }),
    url: loginUrl,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

The response should include "LOGON_OK", but it does not.

I've seen that in the Java-code, there is something about a certificate-file (https://github.com/liato/android-bankdroid/blob/master/bankdroid-legacy/src/main/res/raw/cert_okq8.pem)
The code that I'm talking about is below. What is the procedure that I'm missing?

```
protected LoginPackage preLogin() throws BankException, IOException {
    urlopen = new Urllib(context, CertificateReader.getCertificates(context, R.raw.cert_okq8));
    Date d = new Date();
    List<NameValuePair> postData = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    response = urlopen
            .open("https://nettbank.edb.com/Logon/index.jsp?domain=0066&from_page=http://www.okq8.se&to_page=https://nettbank.edb.com/cardpayment/transigo/logon/done/okq8");
    //p_tranid is the epoch time in milliseconds
    postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p_tranid", Long.toString(d.getTime())));
    postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p_errorScreen", "LOGON_REPOST_ERROR"));
    postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("n_bank", ""));
    postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("empty_pwd", ""));
    postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", getUsername().toUpperCase()));
    postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", getPassword()));
    return new LoginPackage(urlopen, postData, response,
            "https://nettbank.edb.com/Logon/logon/step1");
}
```

Comment: Check the console. You're probably being blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). If so you need to use either JSONP or CORS (assuming the receiving domain supports them - which is unlikely as it appears to be a bank). Your alternative is to use a server-side proxy in Java, ASP.Net, PHP or any other server-side language you care to use.

Comment: You're right, I have to go with PHP which I can do instead. Thanks!